# Deleting a record from array of pointers of my own class type

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have created an Employee class:

```
class Employee {

private:

    int idNumber;
    string name, department, position;

public:
    Employee() {
        idNumber = 0;
        name = department = position = "";
    }

    Employee(string n, int idn) {
        name = n;
        idNumber = idn;

        department = position = "";
    }

    Employee(string n, int idn, string dep, string pos) {
        name = n;
        idNumber = idn;
        department = dep;
        position = pos;
    }

    void setName(string n) {
        name = n;
    }

    void setidNumber(int idn) {
        idNumber = idn;
    }

    void setDepartment(string dep) {
        department = dep;
    }

    void setPosition(string pos) {
        position = pos;
    }

    string getName() {
        return name;
    }

    int getidNumber() {
        return idNumber;
    }

    string getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    string getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

};
```

Now, i created a 2D array of Pointers of type Employee:

```
int n=2;
Employee **p = new Employee * [n];

for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
    p[i] = new Employee;
```

I stored two records successfully as under:

```
Name    ID Number    Department    Position
FS      30           CS            BS
AT      27           CS            BS
```

I have this code to delete the record of Employees:

```
    string del_name;
    int flag = 0;

    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    getline(cin, del_name);

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {

        while (del_name == p[i]->getName() && i < n) {
            if (del_name == p[i]->getName()) {
                delete p[i];
                p[i] = NULL;
                --k;
                ++flag;
                cout << "Record deleted." << endl;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 0;
            }

        }
    }

    if (flag == 0)
        cout << "No record found having name " << del_name << "." << endl;
```

---

### **Now, What's the problem:**

1. If a record is found at multiple times. It deletes successfully even if all the records gets deleted.

   - But if ALL the records are unique and I delete the records one by one and all the records get deleted in this way then the program gets terminated.
2. Also, is there any other optimized approach to delete records without using VECTORS.

I hope i have clearly explained my problem. I can provide further details if needed.

**Thank you for your time**

Comment: Why are you opposed to `vector` (and, presumably, other `std::` containers)? Do you have the same objection to [tag:smart-pointers]?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Nah, i am not opposed to `vector` or other things. It's just that i haven't learnt those things yet.

Comment: @FaizanSaleem - What's stopping you from learning what vectors do?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Currently i want to firm my grip on classes using dynamically allocated pointers.

Comment: I see no classes in your code.  All I see is logic that no C++ programmer worth anything would recommend.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Is there no class in my code? Then what have i written at the very beginning of my question?

Comment: I don't see the class keyword anywhere.  If you're going to post code, don't post descriptions of your code -- actually post the real code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Added the code now.

Answer (score 0):

First, usage of std::vector<> or some other container object is the way to go about this.  If you can write code that beats (in terms of speed) written by professional library writers, then go ahead.

Second, what is your goal?  If it's to simply deallocate entries in that array depending on some criteria, the loop you wrote is overly complex.

```
bool recordDeleted = false;
for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) 
{
    if (del_name == p[i]->getName()) 
    {
        delete p[i];
        p[i] = NULL;
        recordDeleted = true;
    }
}

if ( !recordDeleted )
{
   // record not found
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i know it's complex but i am not getting the reason of my problem i explained above.

Comment: 1) What is the purpose of that while()? `while (del_name == p[i]->getName() && i < n)` 2) Why in the while() loop condition you're checking for i < n? The for() loop condition already limits i to be less than n. 3) Why are you making the same test twice in the while loop?
`{ if (del_name == p[i]->getName()) {`

Comment: And also, if you want to know why your program doesn't work, post a complete but small program, including the main() function.  Those pointers could have been corrupted by the time that code is run, and we have no idea what state your program is in at that point.